# How to unregister from SIP in linphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, sip, linphone

Is there a way to unregister from SIP and re-register when I want in Linphone?

I can't find the unregister function.

Should I destroy the linphone core completely for that?
Or is there a more soft solution?

Currently I am trying to implement it in iOS, but later this will be required for additional platforms.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

```
// Get the default proxyCfg in Linphone
LinphoneProxyConfig* proxyCfg = NULL;
linphone_core_get_default_proxy([LinphoneManager getLc], &proxyCfg);

// To unregister from SIP
linphone_proxy_config_edit(proxyCfg);
linphone_proxy_config_enable_register(proxyCfg, false);
linphone_proxy_config_done(proxyCfg);

// And re-register when want
linphone_proxy_config_edit(proxyCfg);
linphone_proxy_config_enable_register(proxyCfg, true);
linphone_proxy_config_done(proxyCfg);
```

Answer (score 3):

You may have multiple SIP accounts. First, specify the account you want and get your proxy from `getProxyConfigList`. Then remove the proxy you want from the core of the linphone via `removeProxyConfig` method:

```
private static AuthInfo mAuthInfo;
private static ProxyConfig mProxyConfig;

Core core = LinphoneManager.getCore();
ProxyConfig[] proxyConfigs = core.getProxyConfigList();
if (proxyConfigs.length != 0) {
  mProxyConfig = proxyConfigs[0];
  mAuthInfo = mProxyConfig.findAuthInfo();
}

if (core != null) {
{
 if (mProxyConfig != null) {
        core.removeProxyConfig(mProxyConfig);
  }
 if (mAuthInfo != null) {
        core.removeAuthInfo(mAuthInfo);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

there is the way how to unregister using linphone.

Get the LinphoneProxyConfig

```
LinphoneProxyConfig* proxyCfg = NULL;
linphone_core_get_default_proxy([LinphoneManager getLc], &proxyCfg);
```

To unregister from SIP

```
linphone_proxy_config_edit(proxyCfg); /*start editing proxy configuration*/
linphone_proxy_config_enable_publish(proxyCfg, TRUE);
linphone_proxy_config_set_publish_expires(proxyCfg, 0);
linphone_proxy_config_enable_register(proxyCfg,FALSE); /*de-activate registration for this proxy config*/
linphone_proxy_config_done(proxyCfg); /*initiate REGISTER with expire = 0*/


while(linphone_proxy_config_get_state(proxyCfg) !=  LinphoneRegistrationCleared){
    NSLog(@"state = %i",linphone_proxy_config_get_state(proxyCfg));
    linphone_core_iterate(lc); /*to make sure we receive call backs before shutting down*/
    ms_usleep(100000);
}
```

But it's works only when app in Foreground. In background if the OS kills your app for any reason, it is killed. There is no notification. You can't catch the SIGKILL signal. Look at the man page for kill.

Answer (score 0):

Unregistration not exactly given. Remove sip extension and then call refresh registers. Now your softphone unregistered from sip

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:@"username_preference"];


if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]
        && [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState ==  UIApplicationStateBackground
        && [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"disable_autoboot_preference"]) {
        // autoboot disabled, doing nothing
        return;
    } else if ([SipManager instance] == nil) {
        [self startApplication:caldelegate];

    }

    [[LinphoneManager instance] becomeActive];

    if (callCenter == nil) {
        callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
        callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall* call) {
            // post on main thread
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(handleGSMCallInteration:)
                                   withObject:callCenter
                                waitUntilDone:YES];
        };
    }
    // check call state at startup
    [self handleGSMCallInteration:callCenter];

    LinphoneCore* lc = [SipManager getLc];
    LinphoneCall* call = linphone_core_get_current_call(lc);
    if (call == NULL)
        return;

    SipManager* instance = [SipManager instance];
    if (call == instance->currentCallContextBeforeGoingBackground.call) {
        const LinphoneCallParams* params = linphone_call_get_current_params(call);
        if (linphone_call_params_video_enabled(params)) {
            linphone_call_enable_camera(
                                        call,
                                        instance->currentCallContextBeforeGoingBackground.cameraIsEnabled);
        }
        instance->currentCallContextBeforeGoingBackground.call = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Actually, there is no "unregistration" option for a sip server. The location server will update to the newest register information (including your newest IP address).
- If you are talking about how to stop linphone iterate registration, and re-register to the other SIP server. Then follow the @Mun Chun's guide

Answer (score 0):

```
LinphoneCore *lc = [LinphoneManager getLc];
LinphoneProxyConfig *config = linphone_core_get_default_proxy_config(lc);
linphone_proxy_config_edit(config);
linphone_proxy_config_set_expires(config, 0);
linphone_proxy_config_done(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on Linphone for some months and my function to unregister from SIP was:

```
- (void)clearProxies {
    LinphoneProxyConfig *config = linphone_core_get_default_proxy_config(LC); // Get the default proxy configured.

    const LinphoneAuthInfo *ai = linphone_proxy_config_find_auth_info(config);
    linphone_core_remove_proxy_config(LC, config); // Remove the selected proxy config.
    if (ai) {
        linphone_core_remove_auth_info(LC, ai); // Remove the authentication infos.
    }

    linphone_proxy_config_done(config); // Confirm the actual configuration.
}
```

You have to clear both proxy config and auth info and confirm the new configuration.

Comment: @JulianCorrêa so my solution is not correct? When I remove the configuration of the proxy, I'm no longer able to make calls.

Comment: the question is about to unregister and register on SIP, not to remove the proxy. Does not make sense, so, if you clear the proxies, how the app can register in the next open?

The best approach in my opinion is that: https://gist.github.com/juliancorrea/2593721b861418a035e41374a182aa42